# Probability that simple random walk is bounded within $[-M,M]$

Tags: markov-process, random-walk

Suppose $\{ X_n \}$ is a simple random walk that moves to left with probability $p$ and right with probability $1-p$. How can I argue that the probability that the simple random walk stays within arbitrary bounds $[-M,M]$ is 0 ? My initial idea is to use the central limit theorem ..but I am not able to formulate the salient details of this argument. Is this the right approach? If it it can someone suggest how can go about arguing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier than that.  At any point in time you will leave the interval $[-M, M]$ (assuming you haven't already) within $M + 1$ steps with some positive probability.  This probability might be very small, but all that matters is that it's bounded away from zero.  In order for this to *never* happen we must avoid this event an infinite number of times, and this has probability zero.

This is an informal proof, but it's not hard to make it rigorous.  Note this is exactly the logic used in the [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem).